# Do Access Control Sections Need an Authors Field Too?

Tags: lotus-notes

I've been a Notes developer for years but never used an Access Control Section on a Form.

I want to give (web) users (with the right [role]) access to edit only one field on a document. I'm assuming an Access Control Sections is the way to go.

A couple of things aren't obvious:

1. As well as adding the [role] name to the Access section's formula does it also have to exist in an Authors field on the document?
2. If #1 is true, then do all other fields have to also be in an Access Control Section where that role can *not* edit them?

Jake

Comment: You could also limit access to a specific field anywhere in a document by adding an Input Enabled formula to the field on the form. For example, if the formula was only true when the user had the Procurement role, then it would appear as read-only to users who don't have that role. Of course, since that only controls editing, someone could still change the value with an agent or using another form on which it was not disabled, so it only "limits" access rather than "restricting" access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lotus Notes Access is ALWAYS calculated top -> down. 
If you don't have Author- Access to the document itself (defined by an Author- field or because you are Editor or higher) then a Section- Author- Role will not help you.

The answer is: Yes, you need an editor- field containing the role.

In consequence the answer to your second question is also: YES, you need to protect the other fields with a section (without the role) as well, if you really want to restrict access to that single section.

Answer (score 1):

The access control section controls access to what ever is in the section. It does not need an authors field.. Only the content or fields that you want to control access to are included. Authors fields define who can edit a document. Regardless of what level of access a user has, if there is an authors field and the role is not listed, that user will not be able to edit the document.

You can use an authors field to limit the editors to certain documents, from there you can further restrict access to fields to edit by sections. If you do have an authors field in conjunction with a section, the role needs to be in the authors field as well as the section access formula in order to be able to edit

Comment: It is NOT right, that "regardless of what level of access a user has...". Author- fields are quite "weak": They are only relevant for authors... Readers of the database cannot be given access by putting them in an author- field, and Editors (and higher) simply don't care about author- fields, they can edit whatever they see...